# How do i perform manual transactions with Windows ODBC

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, transactions, odbc

How is one supposed to use manually commited/rolled back transactions using the Microsoft Windows ODBC API? The queried SQL server is MS SQL Server if that matters. Language is C++.

I need to include several calls to `SQLExecDirect` into a single transaction in order to guarantee consistency. The executed queries do not use any transactions.

Pseudocode:

```
// Begin Transaction?
SQLExecDirect(...);
SQLExecDirect(...);
SQLExecDirect(...);
SQLExecDirect(...);
SQLExecDirect(...);
SQLEndTran(...);
```

My approach was to disable autocommit first as documented on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175182(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SQLSetConnectAttr(m_hConnection, SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, (void*) SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF, 0);
```

Run my queries and then commit/rollback afterwards:

```
SQLEndTran(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_hConnection, SQL_COMMIT);
```

It does not give any errors, but does not seem to do the trick. If I inspect the transaction log with the MS SQL Management Studio, everything shows up as `implicit_transaction` (Okay), spanning only a single operation (Not Okay).

[image: SSMS Output]

Could this issue be caused by each call to `SQLExecDirect` using its own Statement handle? I was thinking about that, and I could try to change that, but it would be quite a task which I am unwilling to do just because it *could* be.

On the other hand, I have no clue how to debug further. If anyone had any Ideas, I would greatly appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to what I do normally do. A few differences in SQLSetConnectAttr:

1. I do check return value
2. SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF should be casted to SQLPOINTER
3. last parameter should be SQL_IS_UINTEGER and not 0

Everything else seems ok to me...

Comment: I omitted the return value check in my post, of course I do that..No error returned. It is SQL_SUCCESS. Gonna try the other stuff though, thank you. The SQL_IS_UINTEGER might be the key as it's value is -5 not 0.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!